# Can something be 'disponible' if it is in service?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, significado

I've got an assignment to develop a website for monitoring taxis, which makes the following possible:

- Obtener una lista de unidades disponibles
- Obtener una lista de alcaldías disponibles

Now, I thought 'disponible' meant available. 'Availability' doesn't make sense for city districts, which is what I translate 'alcaldía' to. Regarding 'unidades', I would say that 'available' taxis are the ones that are not in use, e.g. they are not in service. Is my interpretation of this sentence correct, and how can I make the other one make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While "available" (*disponible*) does work for taxis to refer to those that are free and can thus be used, it does not for districts.

For districts, I'd use:

- *Obtener una lista de alcaldías **con disponibilidad*** (meaning: with availability -- "of taxis" is implicit)

Comment: But the question is, used by whom? If it is in the garage, is it 'disponible' for the taxi company owner but not for the average citizen? The would mean it has the complete opposite meaning depending on the context...

Comment: "disponible" (an exact equivalent of "available") means that the units CAN be used. "disponible para ser usado" = "available to be used"